# MySQL inverse substr()

Tags: mysql, substr

`select now()` will output `2012-11-20 09:05:38`.

`select substr(now(), locate(' ', now()))` will output `09:05:38`.

How can I obtain this result: `2012-11-20` instead? Been there, done that but can't achieve it yet. Forgive me for my lacking but please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an specific answer to your question about substrings, but if I wanted the DATE part of NOW() I would do:

```
SELECT DATE(NOW());
```

Or for the time portion

```
SELECT TIME(NOW());
```

For actual string purposes though you can use:

```
SUBSTR('SOME STRING', 0, LOCATE(' ', 'SOME STRING')) <- returns from position zero for a length of 4 characters
```

Or

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX('SOME STRING', ' ', 1) <- gives 'SOME'
SUBSTRING_INDEX('SOME STRING', ' ', -1) <- gives 'STRING'
```

Comment: I did update answer to give you idea on how to do for any string as well, but for your cases, I would stick to treating the NOW() like a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2012-11-20 09:05:38', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

or just `DATE`

```
SELECT DATE('2012-11-20 09:05:38')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/3919)

Comment: what do you mean single query? you can run any of the following query.